# Making a Celsius to Fahrenheit conversion table in Java w/ input

Tags: java, loops

Admittedly pretty new to Java again. Taking a class online which asks for a conversion table from Celsius to Fahrenheit with user input asking the current temp in Celsius. The class wants us to use a loop (doesn't specify which) and after some trial and error and googling around I feel like I'm close to getting this to work, but I feel like the `x++` parameter is screwing the conversion output up. Instead of spitting out the conversion, it's just adding 1 continuously.

```
System.out.println("Enter a City : ");
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   String city = input.nextLine();

    //Initiates a string that contains the celsius degree Unicode So i can call it easily.
    final String DEGREE  = "\u00b0";
    double celsius, fahrenheit;

    System.out.println("Enter your temperature in Celsius format for: " + city + " " );
    celsius = input.nextInt();
    fahrenheit = 32 + (celsius * 9 / 5);

    System.out.println("Celsius\tFahrenheit");
    System.out.println("====================");

    for (int x = 0; x <= 40; x++) {

    System.out.print(x + celsius);
    System.out.print("\t\t");
    System.out.print(x + fahrenheit);
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: I am confused- what is the table of?

Comment: In the end, on the left it will display Celsius temperatures starting at the top with the users inputted temperature, all the way up to 40 degrees above. and on the right it displays the fahrenheit conversions for the 40 displayed celsius temps.

Comment: I found the code for the For loop that limits it to 40 here, https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/exercises/celsius-to-fahrenheit-table/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
System.out.println("Enter a City : ");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String city = input.nextLine();

//Initiates a string that contains the celsius degree Unicode So i can call it easily.
final String DEGREE  = "\u00b0";
double celsius, fahrenheit;

System.out.println("Enter your temperature in Celsius format for: " + city + " " );
celsius = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Celsius\tFahrenheit");
System.out.println("====================");

for (int x = 0; x <= 40; x++) {
    System.out.print(celcius + x);
    System.out.print("\t\t");
    System.out.print(32 + ((celsius + x) * 9 / 5));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: You are awesome! Wow, that was in just a couple minutes.. thank you so much. Been trying to figure that out for over an hour now. I got as close to yours as swapping out the 3rd sys.out with the conversion formula like you did but i never swapped in my variable celsius like you did instead of fahrenheit. Thank you man! Saved my night.

Comment: Glad I can help! Make sure to close the question per https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Did you mean `print(celcius + x)`?